# Twitter4j and java Swing

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

In the version 4 of Twitter4j, the only way to log in is with HTTP Request?
Can't I authenticate like this sample?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException{
      LoginDialog login = new LoginDialog();
      String userName = login.getUserName();
      String password = login.getPassword();

      try{
          Twitter twitter = new Twitter(userName, password);
          twitter.verifyCredentials();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, "Login successful!");
      } catch(TwitterException e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, "Unable to login");
      }
  }
```

Comment: You can authenticate yourself using the example outline here https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java and you need a registered twitter app https://apps.twitter.com/ .

If you want to authenticate other people you still need a registered twitter app and probably need to use 3-legged authorisation https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview . 

So no you can't do things how you are describing

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features of OAuth is that the person who is logging in does not have to worry about the site or application having access to their username or password and potentially leaking or misusing that information.